# MOT test failure "fly by wire steering system"

Tags: power-steering, steering-wheel

I have an car with a major MOT fault that is.
Electronic power steering that is 'fly by wire' has the angle of the steering wheel is inconsistent with the angle of the road wheels (2.6 (b) (i))

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue. If I drive the car forward on a flat road my steering wheel is dead center and not rotated to the left or right. So how can the wheels be out of alignment with the steering wheel?

Could this be more to do with how the front wheels are out of alignment with regards to tracking?

Any any suggestions would be good. Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked the MOT centre for clarification? It's their finding, they should be able to explain.

Comment: steering sensor may be faulty.

Comment: The car also had an abs fault on the dash (vcds reported rear left abs sensor faulty) and the mot mechanic said it might be also causing the problem with the steering. But that dosen't seem to make sense. ABS light is electrical system and "angle of steering inconsistent" sounds mechanical/physical issue. He also said something apart a part that is under the steering wheel that might be out of alignment/faulty?

Comment: is it just wheel alignment/tracking required? thinking about it it does seem to pull to one side at high speed

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested it turns out the ABS sensor on the car caused both an ABS light and a traction control light to be displayed on the dash. Replacing the ABS sensor got rid of both lights on the dashboard. The MOT tester thought that there was a fault on both the abs and traction control systems on the car so put down both faults on the failure notice.

Comment: I would expect this. The MOT tester has to record what systems the car is reporting faults on at the time of the test (i.e. both). They can't put an educated guess down instead at what _might_ be the cause, even if they were to do a diagnostic that said the ABS sensor has failed, in case that was not the actual/only cause. The MOT is a basic mechanical check. They're not even allowed to remove covers or under-trays for the inspection.